# my code about multiplying digits recursively isn't giving any output can you help me rectify it

Tags: c++, recursion, multiplication

**this is the code that I have written for multiplying digits recursively**

```
#include<iostream>        

using namespace std;        

int multi(int n){        

    
    int smallanswer=multi(n/10);        

    int lastdigit=n%10;        

    if(n==0) return 1;        
    else return smallanswer*lastdigit;       

}        

int main(){        

    cout<<multi(1234);        

}
```

Comment: my rubber duck wants to know how you are ever going beyond the first line in `multi`

Comment: Consider where to place this line: `if(n==0) return 1;`.

Comment: Consider converting the number to a string then accessing the digits as: `int digit = number_as_string[x] - '0';`

Answer (score 1):

be aware with recursive call: don't forget the "stop recursion" step.

Below code will work:

```cpp
#include<iostream>


int multi_impl(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int smallanswer = multi_impl(n / 10);
    int lastdigit = n % 10;
    return smallanswer * lastdigit;

}

int multi(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return multi_impl(n);

}

int main()
{
    std::cout << multi(1234) << std::endl;
    std::cout << multi(0) << std::endl;
}
```

**Edit** according to [@463035818_is_not_a_number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number) relevant comment.

Comment: note that `multi(0)` will return 1. This can be fixed by renaming it to `multi_impl` and wrapping it into a `multi` that returns `0` when the number is `0`